# Можно ли замостить плиткой размером n на m, площадь размером a на b

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Я в правильном направлении? так как решение не проходит все тесты.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int t;
    cin >> t;
    while (t--)
    {
        int a,b,c,d;
        cin >> a >> b >> c >> d;
        if(!(c % b) && !(d % a) || !(d % b) && !(c % a))
        {
            cout << "YES\n";
        } else {
            cout << "NO\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Можно ли плиткой 3*5 замостить площадку 8*15? По вашему алгоритму - нельзя, а на самом деле - можно. Просто плитку не обязательно укладывать в одном направлении.

Comment: Не знаю с++, но идея с `if(!(c % b) && !(d % a) || !(d % b) && !(c % a))` выглядит сомнительной с точки зрения ухода от двух измерений к одному. Кроме того, по модулю 0 будет и если 10 плиток, взять кратных покрываемой площадке, и 5. Да и условие непонятное тоже - это одна единственная плитка, или много плиток? Если плитка будет больше площади - это тоже ведь является "замостить" или надо ровно-ровно замостить - ни больше, ни меньше?

Comment: Ровно-ровно, ни больше, ни меньше

Comment: Теорема де Брёйна: любая сторона плитки должна делить какую-то сторону площадки: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D0%B4%D0%B5_%D0%91%D1%80%D1%91%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B0#%D0%9E%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5

Comment: 5*6 можно замостить плиткой 2*3. Ваша программа скажет "нет". Я не нашёл в Сети полного решения именно этого случая. :(

Comment: Дайте ссылку на проверяющую систему.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чем ограничиваете цикл,  не понятно(что за t, как вы определяете это значение?). В заголовке у вас `n*m` а в программе  `c*d`. Так что  я проясню: Площадь `c*d` можно замостить плиткой `a*b` если выполняется условие: `if( (c * (b-1)) % r == 0 && (d * (a - 1)) % r == 0)`,  где `r = a - b`. Это математически легко доказывать, и не нужен никакой цикл.

Comment: Для плитки 3*5 и площадки 8*16 ваша формула ` (c * (b-1)) % r == 0 && (d * (a - 1)) % r == 0` дает true. Что точно неверно, поскольку `(8*16) %(3*5)==8`  т.е. площадь площадки не делится на площадь плитки нацело.

Comment: Плиткой `(k + 1, k)` можно замостить всё. Для неё `r = 1`, а на него без остатка делится всё. Что-то тут не так.